# How to vertically align different height divs

Tags: css

I'm trying to vertically align text in a couple of DIV's in a "tabs" bar. The content in each div is different lengths and some take 2 lines (see screenshot):

[image]

```css
#hometabswrap {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px #e1e1e1 solid;
  border-bottom: 1px #e1e1e1 solid;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#hometabs {
  width: 97%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px 25px 0px 25px;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

#hometabs .home_tab {
  padding: 10px 14px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

#hometabs .home_tab_active,
#hometabs .home_tab:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #B22222;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div id="hometabswrap">
  <div id="hometabs">
    <div class="home_tab">
      <a href="" title="Newest Trips">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-plus"></i> NEWEST
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="home_tab">
      <a href="/top-rated" title="Top Rated Trips">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><br>HIGHLY RATED
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="home_tab">
      <a href="/london-airports" title="Trips from London Airports">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-plane"></i><br>LONDON AIRPORTS
      </a>
      <!-- closing </a> was missing in the original question -->
    </div>
    <div class="home_tab">
      <a href="/search/overnight" title="Trips including an overnight stay">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bed"></i> OVERNIGHT
      </a>
      <!-- closing </a> was missing in the original question -->
    </div>
    <div class="home_tab">
      <a href="/search" title="Search Extreme Day Trips">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i> SEARCH
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried adding `align-self: center` which works but changes the height of the div, thus breaking the bottom border positioning and creates white space:

[image]

I've played around with various settings but cannot seem to sort this. I've learnt that changing align-self automatically breaks the auto height setting by default and can't figure out how to do both.

This is what I am after:

[image]

When hovering over a tab, it shows the red border like in the image (NEWEST has red border because thats the current tab) but the red-border is aligned to the bottom.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us how you want it to show. Please.

Comment: @deEr. I've edited it in photoshop to show what I am after. Im halfway there with `align-self: center' but it changes the heights of the divs and the bottom borders are not aligned to the bottom

Comment: Please double-check the image.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHysI.jpg <-- does this work?

Comment: CSS without HTML has no context. We don't know if your selectors are correct, or if there's an easy/easier way to achieve your desired outcome. Please, add the (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code.

Comment: @DavidThomas My apologies - i've also added the HTML to my original question

Comment: @Rhys I took the freedom to edit your question putting your code in a live snippet for the sake of showing that your code doesn't match with what you are describing. `align-self: stretch` on the flex item is like doing `align-items: stretch` on the flex container. You didn't actually say where did you make that attempt by the way. Anyway such styling make the flex item height stretch to the height of the container thus making them all equals (as you can see yourself). I only had to correct the fact you left 2 anchor tag unclosed!

Comment: and in the demo the stretch is not even engaged! but yet the divs are all same height. if you didn't post the html I had actually an answer ready to go.. but now things are no more clear like before

Comment: @DiegoD I literally just found those unclosed anchor tags seconds before I saw your comment. What a stupid mistake on my part!

Apologies for not making the code live, that's so much better to explain the issue so thanks!

I've managed to fix it - whether it's the correct way to do it or not i'm sure someone will let me know. I'll post as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Just add `flex` and `align-items: end;`  in `.home_tab` class to have all text in same height and also defind `height` in  `#hometabs`

example:

```css
     #hometabswrap {
        width: 100%;
        background: #ffffff;
        border-top: 1px #e1e1e1 solid;
        border-bottom: 1px #e1e1e1 solid;
        margin: 20px 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #hometabs {
        width: 97%;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        display: flex;
        padding: 8px 25px 0px 25px;
        justify-content: stretch;
      }

      #hometabs .home_tab {
        display: flex;
        padding: 10px 14px;
        text-align: center;
        align-items: end;
        font-weight: 600;
        border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
      }

      #hometabs .home_tab_active,
      #hometabs .home_tab:hover {
        border-bottom: 2px solid #b22222;
      }
```

```html
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />

    <div id="hometabswrap">
      <div id="hometabs">
        <div class="home_tab">
          <a href="" title="Newest Trips"> <i class="fa-regular fa-plus"></i> NEWEST </a>
        </div>
        <div class="home_tab">
          <a href="/top-rated" title="Top Rated Trips"> <i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i><br />HIGHLY RATED </a>
        </div>
        <div class="home_tab">
          <a href="/london-airports" title="Trips from London Airports"> <i class="fa-solid fa-plane"></i><br />LONDON AIRPORTS </a>
          <!-- closing </a> was missing in the original question -->
        </div>
        <div class="home_tab">
          <a href="/search/overnight" title="Trips including an overnight stay"> <i class="fa-solid fa-bed"></i> OVERNIGHT </a>
          <!-- closing </a> was missing in the original question -->
        </div>
        <div class="home_tab">
          <a href="/search" title="Search Extreme Day Trips"> <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i> SEARCH </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a solution by adding a div inside each tab div, making the parent div `display: flex` and the children div `align-self: center`

It displays correctly now. Whether this is the correct way to do this i'm not sure.

```css
#hometabswrap {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px #e1e1e1 solid;
  border-bottom: 1px #e1e1e1 solid;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#hometabs {
  width: 97%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px 25px 0px 25px;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

#hometabs .home_tab {
  padding: 10px 14px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  display: flex;
}

#hometabs .home_tab_active,
#hometabs .home_tab:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #B22222;
}

#hometabs a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#hometabs .home_tab .home_tab_inner {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="hometabswrap">
  <div id="hometabs">
    <div class="home_tab">
      <div class="home_tab_inner">
        <a href="<?=$baseurl?>" title="Newest Trips"><i class="fa-regular fa-plus"></i> NEWEST</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="home_tab">
      <div class="home_tab_inner">
        <a href="/top-rated" title="Top Rated Trips"><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i> HIGHLY RATED</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="home_tab">
      <div class="home_tab_inner">
        <a href="/london-airports" title="Trips from London Airports"><i class="fa-solid fa-plane"></i> LONDON AIRPORTS</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="home_tab">
      <div class="home_tab_inner">
        <a href="/search/overnight" title="Trips including an overnight stay"><i class="fa-solid fa-bed"></i> OVERNIGHT</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="home_tab">
      <div class="home_tab_inner">
        <a href="/search" title="Search Extreme Day Trips"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i> SEARCH</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```